# The assertTrue doesn't work with phpunit symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

```
$this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
```

he doesn't work !! the url exist

message error:

Failed asserting that false is true

```
class DefunctControllerTest extends WebTestCase

{
  private $client;


protected function setUp()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $this->client = $client;

    $connection = static::createClient();
    $connection->request('POST', '/connection', array('identifiant' => 'login', 'mdp' => 'pass'));
    $this->connection = $connection;

}
  public function testAddDefunct()
{

    $cookieJar = $this->connection->getCookieJar();


    $JSESSIONID = $cookieJar->get('JSESSIONID')->getValue();
    $frsimplifiaauth = $cookieJar->get('frsimplifiaauth')->getValue();


    $JSESSIONIDname = $cookieJar->get('JSESSIONID')->getName();
    $frsimplifiaauthname = $cookieJar->get('frsimplifiaauth')->getName();


    $this->client->request('GET', '/146c0a06-be8e-11e4-8c91-cba28340dea8/add-defunct');


    $this->client->getResponse()->headers->setCookie(new Cookie($JSESSIONIDname, $JSESSIONID));
    $this->client->getResponse()->headers->setCookie(new Cookie($frsimplifiaauthname, $frsimplifiaauth));


    $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());

}
```

Comment: check the values of the status code of the response : `$this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode()` or bebug see in the response content `$this->client->getResponse()->getContent()`

Comment: 302. So the problem he redirecte before setting !! but I don't know how I can solve this problem

Comment: if is a protected (authenticated) route probably redirect to a login page. You can see where the reqeìuest is redirect in the `$this->client->getResponse()->getContent()`

Comment: yes of course the route redirect to login page before setting cookies but me I want to set variables before redirect.

Comment: try using the same client instance for do the second call (the authenticated one named connection) without swap the cookie: it should maintain the session